# How are vector space dimension and basis related?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How are vector space dimension and basis related? (I am new to these concepts and know little to nothing about linear algebra/advanced calculus.) Thank you in advance.

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is the minimal number of elements needed to specify any vector in the space. So the number of elements in a basis = the dimension of the VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Every vector space has a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165684/9754). ([Another proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466879/prove-that-every-vector-space-has-a-basis?rq=1)). In particular, there exists a collection of vectors such that every vector can be written as a finite linear combination of vectors in the collection. We say that such a collection of vectors **spans** the vector space.

If there is a finite collection of vectors that spans a vector space, we say the vector space is finite-dimensional. It is perhaps not immediately obvious, but the minimum number of elements of a collection of vectors that span the vector space is well-defined. This is usually proved through the [Steinitz Exchange Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284792/9754) ([another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337494/9754)).

We call *the minimum number of vectors necessary to span a vector space* the **dimension** of the vector space.